# How to implement retry pattern using c#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

*I have a list of **Proxy Servers**. Using these Proxy Servers, I want to hit URL to get data programmatically. I want to apply **retry pattern** here. For example, If I cannot get data from Proxy Server 1, I would like to hit URL using Proxy Server 2 and so on. What should I write in **ProxyHelper class GetData method** as per good design practices.*

Sample Code :

```
Interface IProxyServer {

    IResponse GetData(String URL);

}

public class ProxyServerA implements IProxyServer {

    public IResponse GetData(String URL)
    {
        //some code
    }

}

public class ProxyServerB implements IProxyServer {

    public IResponse GetData(String URL) {
        //some code
    }

}

public class ProxyHelper {

    public List<IProxyServer> _proxyservers = new List<IProxyServer>(); 
    
    public IResponse GetData(String URL)
    {
    
    // Following the best practices, what should be the code here which will implement retry mechanism
    // and call other available proxy server in case the request is failed.
    
    }
    
    public void Add(IProxyServer proxyserver)
    {
        _proxyservers.Add(proxyserver);
    }

}

void main() {

    ProxyHelper proxyHelper = new ProxyHelper();

    String URL = "www.google.com";
    
    proxyserver.Add(new ProxyServerA());
    
    proxyserver.Add(new ProxyServerB());

    var response = ProxyHelper.GetData(URL);

}
```

Comment: There's no such pattern. There are a *lot* of retry strategies though. What you describe is failing over to another server. Check the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library that allows implementing multiple strategies as needed. If a server fails for example, is there a point of using it the next time just to fail over? Or should the calls switch to another server for some time? That's the `Circuit breaker`

Comment: If a server fails, perhaps due to load, do you keep retrying, increasing the load even further? Or do you wait for a bit? If you wait for a fixed time though, all requests that failed will hit the server at the same time again, bringing it down again. That's why retry times need to be randomized. That's part of the Retry strategy. So is exponential backoff - if a server failed to respond the first 2 times, maybe wait a bit longer the next time

Comment: This is such a common practice that Polly [can be integrated with HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to produce HttpClient instances with preconfigured failover strategies

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So, I have a list of URL.I want to scrap data using these proxy servers. I would be implementing around 10 proxy servers. For each request, if there is some issue, it will pass the request to next proxy server and so on. I don't want to shut down the proxy server in case of failure. If it's possible, I would change the ranking of proxy servers. For example, if Proxy Server 1 fails, I would put the proxy server 1 in the last place of the list and bring the Proxy Server 2 in the list to first place. So, this way, I won't be hitting the dead Proxy server every time.

Comment: Check the link I posted. That's the circuit breaker. If you use HttpClient you won't have to write the code yourself, just configure a circuit breaker strategy for your specific HttpClient. You can combine strategies or create your own without affecting the rest of the code